# dotnet pack warning NU1701 (TargetFramework warning) which followed by CS0234 (missing assembly reference)

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-6.0, nuget-package-restore

I am writing a NuGet package which is to be referenced from another project. Both frameworks are .NET 6.0, OS=Ubuntu. ***Both projects define `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` in `.csproj`.***

- *When I pack the NuGet package, **all is okay** (no errors, no warnings)*
- *When I try to restore the `.nupkg`, in I get a **NU1701 warning**:*

  > warning NU1701: Package 'TestCore 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
- *When I try to run my code, I get a **CS0234 (Error)***:

  > The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'Verisoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**Nuget Package's `.csproj`:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>TestCore</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>Nir Gallner</Authors>
    <Company>VeriSoft</Company>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Allure.Commons" Version="3.5.0.73" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nunit.Allure" Version="1.2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

**Consuming project's `.csproj`:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Allure.Commons" Version="3.5.0.73" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nunit.Allure" Version="1.2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" Version="3.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="TestCore" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="allureConfig.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="log4net.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="TestCore">
      <Path>./TestCoreBuilds</Path>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please note that there isn't a .NET Core 6.0. There is .NET 6.0, and there is ASP.NET Core 6.0, but not .NET Core 6.0. I know, it's confusing. I've updated your question to clarify that, while also improving the formatting a bit. Aside from that, this is an odd problem, and not one I have any insight into; I've published quite a few NuGet packages for .NET but never ran into anything like this.

Comment: I believe we also have such a warning in our (production) build. It doesn't seem to break anything so we ignore it. (But I can't check, as it's weekend, so I'm not at work). The warning might be unrelated to the error

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks for your help. I see your point. Currently, it is not published, rather a local reference, but still...

Comment: @JHBonarius When I reference the DLL directly it works OK. This leads me to conclude it has something to do with the .nupkg. If you have any other leads, I'll take whatever I can get...

Comment: Side note, I found that if the compiler cannot find a specific projectreference, it doesn't throw an error about it. Not even a warning. Just at a certain moment you get a missing namespace thing or so.